# Spring-cloud-client not able to get configurations from Config-server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create Micro-services architecture using spring boot, the only challenge I'm facing at the moment is how to configure spring cloud client to pull all the configurations from the config server, the config server gets all the configurations of the services from the native application as shown below.

Configuration Server Application.Properties File

```
server.port = 8088
spring.profiles.active = native
```

Config Server Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class DemoConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Demo department service.properties file inside Config server

```
server.port = 8081
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka/
management.tracing.sampling.probability = 1.0
```

Demo department service.properties file as a service

```
spring.application.name = department-service
spring.config.import = optional:configserver:http://localhost:8088
```

However the service can not get the configurations from the config server

[image: Image shows the configurations of the spring cloud client inside config server]

[image: Application properties of config server]

[image: Application properties of department service that pulls configurations from the config server]